# Dynamic Way to Map WebGrid Column Name to OrderBy Lambda Expression

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I'm having hard moments with a need to order a grid by a specific column.

The real problem remains when I click in the Grid, a querystring is passed with the name of the column.

I need to have a mapping of each column name of each grid to a lambda expression, to be passed into the query that will be dispatched by the entity framework parser and return the data ordered.

What I really love to have is a class that creates dynamic lambda expressions or basically member calls (properties) - create in some way the nodes that represent the order expression by reflection pointing to the property/columnName or something add to the main query, and return the IQueryable with the node added to my global IQueryable query.

Imagine a grid of Student with 10 students.

|id||name||createdAt|note|

and I want to order by the note.

I must have something like

```
public static class StudentPropertyMapper
{
    static Dictionary<string, Func<IQueryable<Student>, IOrderedQueryable<Student>>> s_mapper = new Dictionary<string, Func<IQueryable<Student>, IOrderedQueryable<Student>>>();

    static StudentPropertyMapper()
    {
        s_mapper.Add("Notes", q => q.OrderBy(e => e.notes));
    }

    public static IOrderedQueryable<Student> OrderedQuery(string columnName, IQueryable<Student> Student)
    {
        return s_mapper[columnName](Student);
    }
}
```

and basically add order node to my global query based on a columnName, but I need to do each mapping for each property.

There is some global way to create that part of lambda expression that creates the lambda based on the name of the columnName that basically represents the call of the property of the type?

Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static Func<T, object> GetPropertyLambda<T>(string propertyName) 
    {
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
        return p => property.GetValue(p, null);
    }
```

Use it as

```
var noteOrderedSudents = students.OrderBy(GetPropertyLambda<Student>("notes"));
```

Notice that the property name must match the Student class property ("notes"). In your example you need to translate "Notes" to "notes", but it's simple string translation.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is for Orderby descending:    
public ActionResult Index()
    {
    var Employees = db.Suppliers.Where(m => m.Status == 1).OrderByDescending(m => m.(your data field from db)).ToList();
                    return View(Employees);
    }

This is orderby Ascending:

public ActionResult Index()
    {
    var Employees = db.Suppliers.Where(m => m.Status == 1).OrderBy(m => m.(your data field from db)).ToList();
                    return View(Employees);
    }
```